# How do stop the second element "li" (of the first ul) from having a bottom border

Tags: html, css

How do stop the second element "li" (of the first ul) from having a bottom border

I basically want to remove the extra border under the "sign in" li

```
#topcleanMenu ul {
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding-right: 60px;
}
#topcleanMenu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
   background: #F5F5F5;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#topcleanMenu ul li:hover {
color: #e56804;
 background: #F5F5F5;
}
#topcleanMenu ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
color: #e56804;
  opacity: 0;
}
#topcleanMenu ul li ul li { 
   background: #F5F5F5;
  color: black;  
}

#topcleanMenu ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(2){
border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(199, 199, 199);
}

#topcleanMenu ul li:hover ul {
   border-left: 1px solid rgb(199, 199, 199);
 border-right: 1px solid rgb(199, 199, 199);
}
```

I attached a image to explain this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8hRt.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just removed this class

```
 #topcleanMenu > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(2){
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(199, 199, 199);
    }
```

and added the following classes to achieve the desired result `#topcleanMenu ul li ul li` is used to create the right border and `#topcleanMenu ul li ul li:last-child` is used to apply the bottom border but only to the last li element of the list

```
#topcleanMenu ul li ul li:last-child  {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(199, 199, 199);
}
#topcleanMenu ul li ul li  {
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(199, 199, 199);
}
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lt3Dh/8/

Comment: I WANT the bottom border to exist under "Edit my details", just not under "Sign in"

Comment: I want "nth-child" property to only target the second "li" of the first "ul", but not the second "ul".

Comment: @Jammi: just use the `#topcleanMenu >ul:nth-child(1)> li:nth-child(2)` selector .That should help.

Comment: Thanks almost there with                                    #topcleanMenu >ul:nth-child(1)> li:nth-child(2)                       But that removes the border-bottom "edit my details" and the border-bottom remains for "Sign in"                                          But when I modified                                                                 #topcleanMenu ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(2)                      It almost has the desired effect, but the "border-bottom" for "sign in" is still there, which I want to remove.

Comment: just change form  `ul:nth-child(1)` to `ul:nth-child(2)`, so the desired selector should be
`#topcleanMenu >ul:nth-child(2)> li:nth-child(2)`.

Comment: I have updated the answer, if it works mark it as answer and close the thread.

Comment: Still not working, I've put it on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jammim19/Lt3Dh/7/                                     also here is a diagram of what it should look like: http://imgur.com/OICqog7